# Python restarts without implementing my code

Tags: python, shell, keras, python-idle

I'm trying to run my code using the python idle. But when ever I'mtrying to run this , after a specific line the shell is getting restarted

```
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D
from keras.layers import concatenate
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, LearningRateScheduler
from keras import backend as K


K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')  # Theano dimension ordering in this code

img_rows = 512
img_cols = 512

smooth = 1.


def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)

def dice_coef_np(y_true,y_pred):
    y_true_f = y_true.flatten()
    y_pred_f = y_pred.flatten()
    intersection = np.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (np.sum(y_true_f) + np.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)

def dice_coef_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return -dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)


def get_unet():
    inputs = Input((1,img_rows, img_cols))
    conv1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)

    conv2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)

    conv3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)

    conv4 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv5)

    #up6 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv5), conv4], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)
    up6 = concatenate([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv5), conv4], axis=1)
    conv6 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv6)

    #up7 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv6), conv3], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)
    up7 = concatenate([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv6), conv3], axis=1)
    conv7 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv7)

    #up8 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv7), conv2], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)
    up8 = concatenate([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv7), conv2], axis=1)
    conv8 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv8)

    #up9 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv8), conv1], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)
    up9 = concatenate([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv8), conv1], axis=1)
    conv9 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv9)

    conv10 = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(conv9)

    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=conv10)

    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1.0e-5), loss=dice_coef_loss, metrics=[dice_coef])

    return model


def train_and_predict(use_existing):
    print('-'*30)
    print('Loading and preprocessing train data...')
    print('-'*30)
    imgs_train = np.load("C:/Users/hirplk/Desktop/unet/Luna2016-Lung-Nodule-Detection-master_new/DATA_PROCESS/scratch/cse/dual/cs5130287/Luna2016/output_final/"+"trainImages.npy").astype(np.float32)
    imgs_mask_train = np.load("C:/Users/hirplk/Desktop/unet/Luna2016-Lung-Nodule-Detection-master_new/DATA_PROCESS/scratch/cse/dual/cs5130287/Luna2016/output_final/"+"trainMasks.npy").astype(np.float32)

    imgs_test = np.load("C:/Users/hirplk/Desktop/unet/Luna2016-Lung-Nodule-Detection-master_new/DATA_PROCESS/scratch/cse/dual/cs5130287/Luna2016/output_final/"+"testImages.npy").astype(np.float32)
    imgs_mask_test_true = np.load("C:/Users/hirplk/Desktop/unet/Luna2016-Lung-Nodule-Detection-master_new/DATA_PROCESS/scratch/cse/dual/cs5130287/Luna2016/output_final/"+"testMasks.npy").astype(np.float32)

    mean = np.mean(imgs_train)  # mean for data centering
    std = np.std(imgs_train)  # std for data normalization

    imgs_train -= mean  # images should already be standardized, but just in case
    imgs_train /= std

    print('-'*30)
    print('Creating and compiling model...')
    print('-'*30)
    model = get_unet()
    # Saving weights to unet.hdf5 at checkpoints
    model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('unet.hdf5', monitor='loss', save_best_only=True)
    #
    # Should we load existing weights? 
    # Set argument for call to train_and_predict to true at end of script
    if use_existing:
        model.load_weights('./unet.hdf5')

    # 
    # The final results for this tutorial were produced using a multi-GPU
    # machine using TitanX's.
    # For a home GPU computation benchmark, on my home set up with a GTX970 
    # I was able to run 20 epochs with a training set size of 320 and 
    # batch size of 2 in about an hour. I started getting reseasonable masks 
    # after about 3 hours of training. 
    #
    print('-'*30)
    print('Fitting model...')
    print('-'*30)
    model.fit(imgs_train, imgs_mask_train, batch_size=2, epochs=10, verbose=1, shuffle=True,
              callbacks=[model_checkpoint])
    print ('bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb')
```

This is the output of idle.

```
 RESTART: C:\Users\hirplk\Desktop\unet\DSB3Tutorial-master\tutorial_code\LUNA_train_unet.py 

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Research\Python_installation\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py", line 36
    from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
Using TensorFlow backend.
------------------------------
Loading and preprocessing train data...
------------------------------
------------------------------
Creating and compiling model...
------------------------------
------------------------------
Fitting model...
------------------------------
Epoch 1/10

=============================== RESTART: Shell ===============================
```

Does this meant my python has crashed? Has anyone experienced this? It worked fine earlier but now I do not have any way of implementing my code

**Do I need to reinstall everything from the beginning**

Comment: What has changed since it last worked okay?

Comment: I tried to reinstall tensorflow with GPU. Cz the code has been running without GPU and it took around 6 hours to implement a single epoch. Then I installed Cudnn 6 and installed tensorflow 1.3 version. But the mistake I did was I tried to install it while the program was running. :( I felt it could be a reason too.. Then I closed it and installed everything. But now the code seems not runnning

Comment: Ooo, it looks like you are running on Windows which has a conniption fit if programs are installed while running.  Maybe you can uninstall the last part (Cudnn or tensorflow) and reinstall it?

Comment: Yes, the process running your code crashed and IDLE started another user process.  Please look at my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48479010/python-shell-getting-restarted, including the part about running from Command Prompt