restart:shell as output when trying to connect mysql with python
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="123456")
if mysql.connector.is_connected():
    print("connected")

I recently installed mysql.connector module (im a newb at python) and whilst trying to connect to the mysql database( i have everything installed and the database seems to be working perfectly fine on its own). This is the output that I get any time i try to run any code related to mysql.connector module.
this is the error : -->
========================================= RESTART: C:\\Users\\niles\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\hi.py =========================================

===================================================================== RESTART: Shell ====================================================================

i have searched the web for anything similar but found nothing
i also tried is_connected variant to see if the connection's established, but it yielded the same result.
any help appreciated
i looked for this on w3schools and yt videos and i expected to see something along the lines of this :
<mysql.connector.connection.MySQLConnection object ar 0x016645F0>

same -
========================================= RESTART: C:\\Users\\niles\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\hi.py =========================================

===================================================================== RESTART: Shell ====================================================================

output appears

https://stackoverflow.com/q/79150607/7976758 You're not alone! https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql-connector-python%5D+RESTART%3A+Shell

I added comment/answer/question to the older question.

I have been fighting with that recently as well for a project i am working on, I have finally succeeded in connecting, must be something to do with windows 11 anyway,
instead of the mysql.connector.connect() method use the class mysql.connector.MySQLConnection() so
old code
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="123456")
new code
mydb = mysql.connector.MySQLConnection(host="localhost", user="root", password='123456', database='databasename')
hope that helps happy coding !!!
